# Binary values don't add up correctly

Tags: c++, sha1

I'm trying to write an implementation of SHA-1 in C++. But for some reason I can't get it to work. Two values won't add up correctly.

I'm using [this](http://www.metamorphosite.com/show-steps?subject=6&topic=17&input=test) link to check the steps of SHA-1 with input `test`

In the first round of the function (for word 0) I have this sample of my code:

```
#define LEFTROTATE(x, c) (((x) << (c)) | ((x) >> (32 - (c))))

a = 0xefcdab89;
b = 0x98badcfe;
c = 0x10325476;
d = 0xc3d2e1f0;

f = (b & c) | (d & (~b));

cout << LEFTROTATE(a, 5); // equal to 3903086636 (11101000101001000110000000101100)

cout << f; // equal to 2562383102 (10011000101110101101110011111110)
```

I want the two values to add up to give me `LEFTROTATE(a, 5) + f`, but I get the following:

```
cout << LEFTROTATE(a, 5) + f; // equal to 2170502442 (10000001010111110011110100101010)
```

I'm expecting the output to be `6465469738 (110000001010111110011110100101010)` since `3903086636 + 2562383102 = 6465469738`. The value decreases for some reason and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal and expected. The addition used in SHA1 is defined as addition modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, which occurs naturally when adding 32bit bitvectors. There is no 33rd bit so it cannot be set.

The linked page shows some extra bits, but that's essentially just for show. They don't affect the result, they get explicitly truncated away on that page before those extra bits get any chance to affect anything.

In practice those bits wouldn't exist in the first place because truncation is implicit.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with this result.

Answer (score 0):

What are the types of your variables? If you're using `unsigned int`, they will overflow. 
Consider using or casting to `unsigned long long`, or `uint64_t`.

Comment: This is for SHA1, they *have to* wrap as 32bit integers

Comment: I believe Cartman123 wants to print `LEFTROTATE(a, 5) + f` and get `6465469738` - for that, he needs to use 64-bit integers